# Google map api search markers with conditions

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to see these markers which fulfill the conditions.
If I tested I write min: 1000, Max 1700 - I see 5 marker but 2 are wrong.
If i change the conditions still wrong.

I post the coda here, maybe anyone can help me to find my problem solution

```
 function searchMarkers()
 {
 var i;

 var mini = document.getElementById("minValue").value;
 var maxi = document.getElementById("maxValue").value;

 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {   
 if (mini < markers[i].weight && markers[i].weight < maxi) {
 markers[i].setVisible(true);
 }
 else {
 markers[i].setVisible(false);
 }
 }
 }
```

I thing something in the searchMarkers function is bad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse you array data to float, otherwise the comparison inside the if will fail.

Instead of your searcMarkers() function, implement the new searchMarkers() function.

Here is the code: you can also see in the alert box that the condition is now valid and it does the comparison as it should be.

function code:

```
 function searchMarkers()
 { 
 var i;

 var mini = document.getElementById("minValue").value;
    alert(mini);
 var maxi = document.getElementById("maxValue").value;
    alert(maxi);

 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {   
 if ((mini) < parseFloat(markers[i].weight) && parseFloat(markers[i].weight) < maxi) {
    alert(markers[i].weight);
 markers[i].setVisible(true);
 }
 else {
 markers[i].setVisible(false);
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: I think that you realize now why the fiddle is important, cheers.